# jquery .fadeOut and .fadeIn smooth page layout transitions

Tags: jquery

I have some simple jquery to display images when catagory selectors are clicked (small snippet)

```
$(".graphic-design-selector").click(function(){
    $(".web-design, .photography").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".design").fadeIn(1000);

});

$(".photography-selector").click(function(){
    $(".web-design, .design").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".photography").fadeIn(1000);

});
```

... etc. Classes 'design', 'web-design' and 'photography' contain images. My problem is that when the page layout reajusts, the transition is really choppy. When the classes have faded out, there is no smooth transition for the page layout before the next classes fade in.

Is there a way with jquery to overcome this and have smooth page layout transitions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a SPA?  If so, jqMobile has smooth transitions from page to page.

Comment: SPA: Single Page Application for OP's reference.

Comment: No its not single page, but I will look into this anyway for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you'll want to do is to wait until the fadeOut is complete before trying to fadeIn.  As it is right now, your fadeOut and fadeIn are competing, which is causing your chop.

Try this...

```
$(".graphic-design-selector").click(function(){
    $(".web-design, .photography").fadeOut(1000, function() {        
        $(".design").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Scottie, definitely see this logic and have applied it. It has ordered the fade in and fade out, so thanks for that, but it hasn't affected the chop of the page layout. When the class fades out, (effectively creating css property of display:none) the classes set to fadeIn do so in the position as if the previous fadeOut of a class has not happened. After they have fully faded in, the elements in the class then jump to their rightful position. I think I need some sort of layout transition to bridge the fadeOut and fadeIn, is there anything to do this?

Comment: Could you do a show with an opacity of 0 and then fade in?